# Is anything known about these types of linear operators?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix, and let $x_{0}\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, for some $n$. Consider $$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax,\,x(0)=x_{0}$$
with solution $x=e^{At}x_{0}$. If there is a norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ such that $\Vert e^{At}x\Vert<\Vert x\Vert$ for all $t>0$ and all $x\ne0$, then the solution $x(t)$ approaches zero with decreasing norm. Is anything known about this type of matrix $A$?

Comment: You mean something like "all eigenvalues have negative real part"?

Comment: @LutzL Yes, but as far as I understand, all eigenvalues having negative real part only means that 0 is asymptotically stable; that is, there is _some_ neighbourhood of 0 where, for any initial condition $x_{0}$ in the neighbourhood, $x(t)\to 0$. My question is about $x(t)$ approaching 0 with decreasing norm for _all_ $t>0$. I am using Ordinary Differential Equations by Arnold, p. 212, if it helps.

Comment: The restriction to a small neighborhood is only for general non-linear ODE, so that the ODE behaves approximately like the linearized system. If the system is linear from the start, it is equal to its linearized system everywhere, thus the neighborhood is the  whole of $\Bbb R^n$.